# Wordpress hover css menu meaning?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am just newbie to the wordpress. I was going through wordpress custom theme designing. In css when I was changing the menu css I came through this css for hover style.
`#access li:hover > a,#access a:focus{ }`
Here can someone tell me what is the meaning of this `#access li:hover > a,#access a:focus`.How it controls the attributes for hover?. I am just newbie so before down voting my question any help and suggestions will be more helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

`#access li:hover>a, #access a:focus` is a selector that applies the rules to two sets of elements:

1. `a` elements that are direct children (`>`) of `li` elements that are being hovered over and are descendants of an element with an `id` attribute of `access`
2. `a` elements that have focus (i.e. tabbed to with a keyboard, clicked on with a mouse) and are descendants of an element with an `id` attribute of `access`